# Is it possible to map subdomain to a folder in S3 bucket?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I'm migrating stating content from Google Cloud to S3. Let's say we have `static.example.com`. Currently, all the static html is referring to something like `static.example.com/project1/css/main.js`. So, in Google Cloud Storage we have directory structure like this.

```
/
|--project1
   |--index.html
|--project2
|--project3
```

We want to migrate everything to S3 with the same subdomain. However, there's another team who want to use the same bucket because we're going to buy a SSL Cert for `static.example.com`. What I imagine the structure of new S3 would be.

```
/
|--team1
    |--project1
       |--index.html
    |--project2
    |--project3
|--team2
    |--project1
```

However, if we do that `project` has to update all the code to be `static.example.com/team1/...`

Is it possible to map `static.example.com` to S3 only for `team1` folder? and then I can do `static.team2.example.com` to S3 for `team2`? I realise that this might not be possible so any suggestion to make this less of hassle please suggest.

Comment: Don't but an SSL cert planning to "install" it on S3.  It does not work that way.

Comment: You really need to look into more of how SSL certs work before proceeding.  A cert for "static.example.com" will not work for "static.team2.example.com."  "team2 static.example.com" would work, if the cert were a wildcard, remembering that a wildcard is good for only one "dot" level in the hostname.  To get your own cert working with S3 *requires* that you use CloudFront or your own proxy, and if CloudFront, you only get SNI without a substantial fee, so your clients must support it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - just use different buckets for the two teams on S3.  Team 1 would use static.example.com, and team 2 would use team2.static.example.com.